# Can't import typescript module

Tags: typescript, npm, webpack

I'm using the following boilerplate as a start:

https://github.com/rokoroku/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate

I am trying to import a node_modules that has only ts files. I install it from a local directory which looks like this:

```
/abc-def
  /src
    /index.ts
  /package.json
```

The package.json of this dep looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "@abc/def",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "main": "./src/index.ts",
}
```

I installed it, works fine

```
yarn add file:../abc-def
```

It shows up in node_modules under `@abc/def` and in the `package.json` of the boilerplate fine:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@abc/def": "file:../abc-def"
}
```

Although, when I run the project, typescript complains it can't find the dependency for some reason, I can't import it.

```
import Def from '@abc/def';
```

> ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/containers/App/index.tsx:10:23 
>       TS2307: Cannot find module '@abc/def'.

I tried to replace the `ts` file by a `js` file and it works fine, although it doesn't want to import the `ts` file directly. There must be some `ts` configuration to change but I'm not sure which ones.

I went through the [TS module resolution documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html) but still can't figure out the right way to modify the tsconfig.json file.

Any idea why I can't import ts files directly?

Thanks

**Edit:**

Just found out if I move the entry file to the root folder of my module, so moving `src/index.ts` to `index.ts`, it works fine. It seems like the typescript resolution doesn't read the `main` field from the `package.json` file. Is this a bug?

I've output the resolve stack, interesting to see it ignores the `main`  field from the `package.json`:

```
======== Resolving module '@abc/def' from '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/src/containers/App/index.tsx'. ========
Explicitly specified module resolution kind: 'NodeJs'.
Loading module '@abc/def' from 'node_modules' folder, target file type 'TypeScript'.
Directory '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/src/containers/App/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Scoped package detected, looking in 'abc__def'
Directory '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/src/containers/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Scoped package detected, looking in 'abc__def'
Directory '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/src/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Scoped package detected, looking in 'abc__def'
Found 'package.json' at '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/node_modules/@abc/def/package.json'.
File '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/node_modules/@abc/def.ts' does not exist.
File '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/node_modules/@abc/def.tsx' does not exist.
File '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/node_modules/@abc/def.d.ts' does not exist.
'package.json' does not have a 'typings' field.
'package.json' does not have a 'types' field.
File '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/node_modules/@abc/def/index.ts' does not exist.
File '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/node_modules/@abc/def/index.tsx' does not exist.
File '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/node_modules/@abc/def/index.d.ts' does not exist.
Scoped package detected, looking in 'abc__def'
File '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/react-redux-typescript-boilerplate/node_modules/@types/abc__def.d.ts' does not exist.
Directory '/Users/alexmngn/Workspace/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Scoped package detected, looking in 'abc__def'
Directory '/Users/alexmngn/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Scoped package detected, looking in 'abc__def'
Directory '/Users/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Scoped package detected, looking in 'abc__def'
Directory '/node_modules' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Scoped package detected, looking in 'abc__def'
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I have the same problem, I can't import the `@sentry/browser` module (unscoped modules work fine). Renaming my .ts file to .js also solves the problem. Using typescript 3.7.5.